# Find a string when "hidden" in other characters

Tags: python

I want to search for strings that have been obfuscated in larger strings. But only to a limited extent. Possibly within 10-15 characters, and case-insensitive.

I found a solution that I think might start do the trick for finding the strings, but it searches the entire target string, when I only want to find results that are close together.

```
def f(orig, word):
    idx = 0
    for letter in word:
        x = orig.find(letter, idx)
        if x != -1:
            idx = x
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

Lets say I have an original string of "4X5G"
And I have the following targets:

1. "Ipsum 47 loreix 5-g blue scuba rock."   4X5G are 13 characters apart, I would want to return this a potential candidate.
2. ""Ipsum 47 loreix blue scuba 5-g rock." 4X5G are 24 characters apart, I would NOT want to return this a potential candidate.

I'm worried that this might become incredibly computationally costly when it comes to large target strings?

Comment: Simple: normalize the string to lowercase, find the first character, then find the second in the rest of the string and so on...

Comment: Instead of using "find", try iterating over string by yourself. When you find the first character remember it's index and then only iterate over 10-15 characters before breaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex to match the string with wildcards in between each letter. You can then use a look-ahead to ensure the size of the match:

```py
import re

s = "Ipsum 47 loreix 5-g blue scuba rock"

print(re.search(r"(?=.{9,14}g)4.*?x.*?5.*?g", s))
```

See [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/j82sGT/2).

To dynamically construct the pattern, you can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). So your function can be:

```py
def f(orig, word):
    pattern = rf"(?=.{{9,14}}{word[-1]})" + r'.*?'.join(word)
    return bool(re.search(pattern, orig, re.IGNORECASE))
```

Test cases:

```
>>> f("Ipsum 47 loreix 5-g blue scuba rock", "4X5G")
True
>>> f("Ipsum 47 loreix blue scuba 5-g rock", "4X5G")
False
```

Comment: Thank you, I like this a lot.   I had an epiphany last night that I would be better off doing this in SQL and having the database do the lifting.  So now I'm heading down the rabbit hole of how to implement this in MSSQL since look aheads aren't supported regex in MSSQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
string = '4X5G'
list_of_chars = list(string)
candidate = 'Ipsum 47 loreix 5-g blue scuba rock.'.lower()

pos = 0
first_pos = None
last_pos = 0
for el in list_of_chars:
    if el.lower() in candidate:
        pos = candidate.index(el.lower(), pos)
        if first_pos == None:
            first_pos = pos
        last_pos = pos
    else:
        raise Exception

if last_pos - first_pos < 15:
    print(candidate)
```

First we need to check if every character is in candidate, changing start index each time we find char. Then just checking first and last poses, if their difference is acceptable.